# Magento2: Can't create bundle product at backend

Tags: magento2, bundled-product

I'm using Magento version 2.1.1 and trying to create a bundle product in admin. By default the product page chooses "**Default**" attribute set and when I change it to other attribute set

e.g. "Rooms" (my custom attribute set) its just loading and firebug showing the error attached in the file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved it. Actually, my custom attribute set did not have "Bundle Items" group in it. So I've created it and then moved the product attribute "shipment_type" under it. Now, I can create bundle products under my custom attribute set.

[image: screenshot]